# blazor.webassymbly routing with URL parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using a URL parameter as follows in my .razor page

```
@page "/VehicleBody-CategorizedData"
@page "/VehicleBody-CategorizedData/{PageNumber:int}"
```

Also, in my `index.html` page I've following JS tag:

```
<script src="/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
```

But, when I try to use `PageNumber` parameter in my page, I get following error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

I've attached console error:
[image]

Here is my project configuration:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UseBlazorWebAssembly>true</UseBlazorWebAssembly>
    <ValidateExecutableReferencesMatchSelfContained>false</ValidateExecutableReferencesMatchSelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="7.0.1" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Have you added `[Parameter]` attribute to the `PageNumber`?

Comment: @Ali, For better help, please put your entire `VehicleBody-CategorizedData` component code in your question. It is probably related to how the variable is defined.